# Display functions used by GUI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface

I'm dealing with complex GUIs in MATLAB.
Is there a fast way to track down and display the functions that I am using?

For example:
When I use the GUI and I am pressing a button or selecting a string from a menu, I would like to display all the functions that were used by the GUI in the command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Matlab profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to track all the functions that were invoked by the GUI. Just press **Run and Time** from the editor menu.

The following code can print the functions that were used:

```
p = profile('info')
numEvents = size(p.FunctionHistory,2);
for n = 1:numEvents
    name = p.FunctionTable(p.FunctionHistory(2,n)).FunctionName;
    disp([name]);
end
```